# Output Redirection

Tags: command-line, pipe, io-redirection, tee

I am using the `tee` command to output the compilation errors of a program into a file along with the terminal.

```
gcc hello.c | tee file.txt
```

This is the command I have used. The compilation errors are displayed on the terminal but they are not outputted in the file. How should I output the std errors into file?

Comment: OK, good. Any question ?

Comment: `tee` only redirects stdout, compilation errors are presumably being output to stderr. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe) for more info on redirecting stderr with `tee`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `csh`, `tcsh`, `zsh` or recent versions of `bash`, try

```
gcc hello.c |& tee file.txt
```

where

- |& instruct the shell to redirect standard error to standard output.

In other Bourne-like shells:

```
gcc hello.c 2>&1 | tee file.txt
```

In `rc`-like shells:

```
gcc hello.c >[2=1] | tee file.txt
```

In the `fish` shell:

```
gcc hello.c ^&1 | tee file.txt
```

Comment: This is a bash 4 feature. For older versions of bash, use `2>&1 |` instead.

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann, that's a `(t)csh` feature, also available in `zsh` and recently added to `bash`.